# Is `-moz-transform: scale(2)` equivalent to CSS `zoom: 2`?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Is `-moz-transform: scale(2)` equivalent to CSS `zoom: 2`?

I tried `-moz-transform` but unlike `zoom` it cuts the top portions off my webpage.

```
function zoomOneX() {
    document.body.style.zoom = 1.2;    
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
        $('body').css('-moz-transform', 'scale(1.2,1.2)');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, scale doubles the size of the element

Zoom zooms you in twice as much

`transform: scale(2)` = Double the size affecting the actual size

`zoom:2` = Zooms twice as much as the current zoom but it does NOT affect the actual size of the element

Comment: Is there an alternative to transform that works on Firefox and gives you the same functionality as zoom which works only in IE, Chrome and Safari? The top portions of my website are cut off when I use transform.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure but you may just have to use scale and adjust the positioning of the element using `position:relative` and playing around with it there

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say they're equivalent. The `zoom` property in CSS allows you to scale your content like the zoom function of a camera, while `transform: scale` affects the size of the element, and by doing so affects the surrounding elements.

See: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/
And: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/